# MVC Inline SVG file adding using Html.Raw

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have a CorelDraw created SVG file that needs to be displayed on a webpage and then do some Javascript on it.  The created .SVG file can be opened in both Chrome and IE9 when you double click on it on Windows Explorer, but when put on a MVC application it opens only on Chrome. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="svgbox" style="border: 1px solid black">
    @Html.Raw(Model.SVGData)
</div>
```

And the controller that gets the SVG data:

```
viewmodel.SVGData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(svgFileName);
```

My ViewModel has:

```
public string SVGData { get; set; }
```

My _shared view has:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Any ideas of how to make this work in IE9 ?

Rds.

**[EDIT]**

I have built a simple code to check this error. So I have the following Index.html:

```
@model TestSVGIE9.ViewModel.TestViewModel

<h2>File: @Model.SVGFileName </h2>

@Html.Raw(Model.SVGData)
```

The controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestSVGIE9.ViewModel;

namespace TestSVGIE9.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            TestViewModel viewModel = new TestViewModel();

            string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/");
            string SVGFileName = path + "Test.svg";

            viewModel.SVGFileName = SVGFileName;
            viewModel.SVGData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(SVGFileName);

            return View(viewModel);
        }

    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestSVGIE9.ViewModel
{
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public string SVGFileName { get; set; }
        public string SVGData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the SVG File (simple red circle, this time created using InkScape):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="744.09448819"
   height="1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   sodipodi:docname="New document 1">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="375"
     inkscape:cy="520"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="706"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
       id="path2985"
       sodipodi:cx="312.85715"
       sodipodi:cy="289.50504"
       sodipodi:rx="104.28571"
       sodipodi:ry="91.428574"
       d="m 417.14286,289.50504 a 104.28571,91.428574 0 1 1 -208.57143,0 104.28571,91.428574 0 1 1 208.57143,0 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Working on Chrome (showing SVG on index page). Not working on IE9...

Help appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the content type be different for SVG content?  Currently you have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

For SVG content, I think you'd need this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: You are right about that, but... I have changed but made no difference at all. It´s being shown in Chrome but not in IE9.

Comment: @Mendez: Interesting.  Between that and the `X-UA-Compatible` content you already had, that's all I've seen for SVG content in IE9.  What `DOCTYPE` are you using?  Can you try explicitly using the HTML5 DOCTYPE?  Would it be possible for you to provide a live (albeit stripped down) example of this?

Comment: Simple <!DOCTYPE html>
I´m now building a small project just to load the SVG data for testing... The strange thing is that the SVG opens in IE9 with no problems outside the application. Sure is something related to the way I´m loading its data...

Comment: @Mendez: I don't have a handy way to test this, so I'm mainly guessing based on past experience now... Perhaps IE doesn't like that `<?xml` opening tag in the middle of an otherwise HTML DOM?  If you can parse out just the SVG content and embed only that, it might work.